# 3D model exported from SketchUp to three.js looks terrible

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, sketchup

Cheers,

I'm using a SketchUp 3D model in a Mapbox custom layer (with threebox/THREE.js) and I'm having a problem getting it to look less than awful.

The model looks great in SketchUp but when I add it to Mapbox, the lights are all messed up. The triangles seem to have individual directional light sources that point all over the place.

[image: SketchUp model]

And this is what it looks like after exported (as .OBJ + .MTL) and imported:

[image: Model in Mapbox]

The `onAdd` looks like this:

```
      onAdd: function(map, gl) {
        this.tb = new Threebox(map, gl, { defaultLights: true });

        const baseName = "hanse388_006";

        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        new THREE.MTLLoader(manager).load(
          baseName + ".mtl",
          function(materials) {
            materials.preload();

            new THREE.OBJLoader(manager).setMaterials(materials).load(
              baseName + ".obj",
              function(object) {
                this.boat = this.tb.Object3D({ obj: object, units: "meters" });
                this.boat.setCoords([DEFAULT_LNG, DEFAULT_LAT, 0]);
                this.tb.add(this.boat);
              }.bind(this)
            );
          }.bind(this)
        );
```

The default lights from threebox (slightly changed by me) look like this:

```
        this.scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.6 ) );
        var sunlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.7 );
        sunlight.position.set(0,80000000,100000000);
        sunlight.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
        this.world.add(sunlight);
```

Comment: Is it possible to export with SketchUp to `glTF` instead? If so, please try this 3D format and load your model with `GLTFLoader`.

Comment: Thank you, Mugen87, I will try that and report back.

Comment: Cool beans. SketchUp doesn't have glTF export but when I exported with Collada it worked as expected! Thank you, @Mugen87 !

Comment: Okay, but keep in mind that `glTF` will load faster than Collada. It would be great if a direct export to `glTF` would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround suggested by @Mugen87, I tried the export/import in a different format.

SketchUp doesn't support glTF but when I used Collada (.dae) it worked nicely!

[image: Collada model]

Comment: Can you share the .obj file that didn't load somewhere?

Comment: Here it is, @gman: https://storage.googleapis.com/naked-sailor.appspot.com/experimental/hanse388_006.obj